# stop playing audio when navigating to another pages, vue.js

Tags: vuejs2, vue-router, html5-audio

I am working on a spa using laravel and vue, I want to play a background music only in home page not in other pages, i have simplified my codes to make my point

this my routes.js codes

```
import home from './components/main.vue';
export const routes = [

    {
        path: '/',
        component: home,
        name: 'home'
    },
]
```

this my root.vue

```
<template>
    <div>
        <navigation></navigation>
        <router-view></router-view>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import navigation from './nav';
export default {
      components:{
  navigation
},
}
</script>
```

this is nav.vue

```
 <template>
        <div>
         <nav>
                            
<i class="fas fa-volume-slash" id="mute" v-if= "this.$route.name == 'home'" v-show = "mute" @click = "play"></i>

 <i class="fas fa-volume-up" id="speaker" v-if= "this.$route.name === 'home'" v-show= "!mute"  @click = "play"></i>
      <!-- i want music i con to be seen only in home page -->
         </nav>
         <audio style="display: none;" id="backMusic">
            <source src="uploads/audio/music.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
        </audio>
        </div>
    </template>
    
    <script>
    export default {
        data(){
            return{
                mute: true,
                audio2: null,
            }
        },
        methods:{
           
           play(){
                if(this.mute){
                    this.audio2.play();
                   this.audio2.loop = true;
                    this.mute = false;
                }else{
                    this.audio2.pause();
                    this.mute = true;
                }
            },
        },
         mounted(){
         this.audio2 = document.getElementById('backMusic');
      }
    }
    </script>
```

finally this app.js

```
Vue.component('root-view', require('./components/root.vue').default);
 
 import {routes} from './routes.js';

const router = new VueRouter({
    routes,
    mode: 'history',
});

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    router,
    store
});
```

when i navigate to login page music still plays! when i navigate to anywhere music still plays
how can i stop
there is no audio tag or javascript audio variable in other pages but still it goes on playing

thank you

p.s: i didnt know how to create jsfiddle containg 2 pages(to navigate)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I read some Q&A in stackoverflow and i finally got the answer

i just add watch to my nav.vue which includes audio

in any redirect i run this code to stop audio

nav.vue

```
 watch:{
        $route (to, from){
            this.audio2.pause();
         }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are also able to you use [beforeRouteLeave](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html#using-the-options-api)

```
beforeRouteLeave(to, from, next) {
   this.play()
   next()
},
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Nuxt.js you can add

`beforeMount(){ initializedAudio.pause(); this.isPlaying = false; },`

into your nav or header